# Supress JS alerts when using Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

This is very strange behaviour that I have observed. When there is simply the following in a webpage, Invoke-WebRequest will give an alert message and pause any scripts until the alert is dismissed.

```
<script>
alert('testing');
</script>
```

[image]

I found an example online so you all may easily replicate.

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'http://activelab.io/code-snippets/show-alert-box-on-page-load'
```

Here is the strangest bit. I have tried quite a lot to avoid this alert. `-UseBasicParsing` is not an option in my case. So I tried to assign the object to a variable and access only the parts that do not have any mention of the alert. For instance:

```
$x = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://activelab.io/code-snippets/show-alert-box-on-page-load'
$x.Forms
```

But this still generates the alert message! Not even `$null = $x.Forms` or similar tricks can stop it.

Even stranger, this is only returned one time. So for instance:

```
$x = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://activelab.io/code-snippets/show-alert-box-on-page-load'
$x.Forms
$x.Forms
$x.Forms
```

Returns a single message. Only when I re-invoke the request can I receive an additional error.

I also tried running it in a job, but this still creates the alert. The job pauses until it is dismissed.

Does anyone have any knowledge about how to work around this issue without using the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter?

Comment: Could you expand on why `-UseBasicParsing` is not usable for you?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ `-UseBasicParsing` will not populate `$request.Forms`, meaning that I would have to implement HTML/JS parsing to determine input fields.

Comment: Ah, so you want to iterate through the forms/fields?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Exactly, though I didn't think it was very relevant to the problem, really. I feel like this should be solvable without just creating a work-around for my specific case.

Comment: Perhaps using `-UseBasicParsing` to download the HTML to a local file and and parsing that using a DOM is an option?  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26009.getting-information-from-web-pages-via-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues with the SSL at `'https://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_alert_box_example_2.cfm'`.  I'm getting:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'https://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_alert_box_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I had to change it to: `'https://64.73.217.183/javascript/javascript_alert_box_example_2.cfm'` then I could test it within PS 4.x.

How about this idea - using `Try{}` `Catch{}`?

```
Try {
    Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'https://64.73.217.183/javascript/javascript_alert_box_example_2.cfm'
} Catch {
 "$_"
}
```

Due to the "$_" produces only simple

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

If you do not want any error just remove or tag out the `"$_"`.

If you want a complete resource on powershell error handling you should read the [*The Big Book of PowerShell Error Handling*](https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/the-big-book-of-powershell-error-handling/)

**Re-Edit** It apparently is not that easy to close the `alert` box.  From my investigation it appears to be kind of iexplorer instance within a powershell.

In my opinion, based on my research, there is no way to "suppress" the alert window shown.

Howerver, you could do it this way (a workaround):

One script is the original one:

```
$x = Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'http://activelab.io/code-snippets/show-alert-box-on-page-load'
$x.Forms
```

The second one is to close the window (you need to have WASP (Windows Automation Snap-in for Powershell) module):

```
Import-Module WASP
start-Sleep -Seconds 15
$web_alert = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -
Like 'Message from webpage' } # this is what identifies the window (based on your example)
select-window $web_alert | Set-windowActive | send-keys '{Enter}' # press enter
```

Then have a third one something along these lines which should start the scripts asynchronously in background (this is just a quick-shot you could you something fancy like [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob):

```
$jobA = Start-Process PowerShell -Argument 'C:\script1.ps1'
$jobB = Start-Process PowerShell -Argument 'C:\script2.ps1'
```

Comment: I guess that's what I get from using some random person's website. I edited the link to a non-ssl site that demonstrates the behaviour. Unfortunately it does not use powershell's event handlers, so I cannot catch it.

Comment: @JacobColvin well the previous link generated the errors within the powershell.   If you are getting a window then it is different story, but still catch-able with try and catch blocks.  I'll update the answer.  Could you elaborate why the `-UseBasicParsing` is not an option for you?

Comment: `-UseBasicParsing` will not populate `$request.Forms`, meaning that I would have to implement HTML/JS parsing to determine input fields.

Comment: @JacobColvin Now I understand what you want to do... :)

Comment: Also your try/catch isn't catching anything. Output $x or any child of $x and the window will still appear.

Comment: @JacobColvin yes, I did not play with the Forms yet.  I did only assigment to `$x`.  I have think about better solution...

Comment: I took a look at your edit, how are you getting the `HtmlWebResponseObject` from your `$jobX` variables?

Comment: @JacobColvin why you should do that?  All logic should be in the `script.ps1` everything else is there just for the workaround.  The `script2.ps1` closes the nasty window and the `script3.ps1` is there for the scripts to run asynchronously.  (If you would put it to one script the window will be still there, but the closing part would run).

Comment: Okay, kind of jank but I definitely see how that works now. Of course I'm going to leave the bounty up for the full time, but I'll accept this if we don't see anything better.

Comment: @JacobColvin I have to agree that the solution is far from beautiful.  That is caused by these: 1) Javascript alert window was not designed to be closed via script 2) imposed limitations in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Make the call with `-UseBasicParsing`

```
$Request = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://activelab.io/code-snippets/show-alert-box-on-page-load' -UseBasicParsing
```

*EDIT: I know you stated you cannot use `-UseBasicParsing` but the point here is that you don't have to implement your own parsing. You can use the same parsing that Invoke-WebRequest uses after modifying the response to avoid alerts. This way you can have `$request.forms` populated without having any alerts.

Modify the response HTML to override alert popups.

```
$JavascriptAlertOverride = @"
// Override window.alert
  window.alert = function() {
    // do nothing here
  };

// Override alert
  alert = function() {
    // do nothing here
  };
"@
$NonAlertingHTML = $Request.Content -replace "<head>", "<head><script type='text/javascript'>$JavascriptAlertOverride</script>"
```

Then parse it back to a full IHTMLDocument and you will have access to `.forms` now and any other property that would be on Invoke-WebRequest except you will not have an alert.

```
$HTML = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$HTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($NonAlertingHTML)
$HTML.forms

PS > $HTML.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                  
True     False    HTMLDocumentClass                        System.__ComObject                                                                                                        



PS > $Request.ParsedHtml.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                  
True     False    HTMLDocumentClass                        System.__ComObject
```

Comment: You did not read the OP properly.  To quote: *"-UseBasicParsing is not an option in my case. "*

Comment: I did actually read it but I also read his comment on why he believes he can't use it "-UseBasicParsing will not populate $request.Forms, meaning that I would have to implement HTML/JS parsing to determine input fields" meaning he is not aware that he does not have to implement his own parsing. He can use the same parsing engine that Invoke-WebRequest does after modifying the response. I will try to clarify that in the answer though and write another option if he happens to be on 2.0 where -UseBasicParsing is literally not an option.

Comment: In the end I have to award it to @tukan but with some additional work, I think this is a good solution. You still need to parse the tree so I guess it depends on how the HTMLDocument will structure varying trees. The HtmlWebResponseObject is still more standard here I believe.

Comment: @JacobColvin Thank you.  I have up-voted this too as it is interesting contribution.